# Use a class on a DIV on specific content with Omega

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

I'm using Drupal 7 and my theme is [Omega](https://www.drupal.org/project/omega). I have got a class "`mask`" and its CSS code is like so:

```
.mask {
    background:url("../img/header_mask.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%!important;
    z-index:101
}
```

I'm creating a class on Omega theme options to show content top, but my div shows on every page. So, I want show this class only on node pages.

```
This is my node.tpl.php:
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <?php print $user_picture; ?>

  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if (!$page): ?>
    <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

  <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
    <div class="submitted">
      <?php print $submitted; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php
      // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      print render($content);
    ?>
  </div>

  <?php print render($content['links']); ?>

  <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>

</div>
```

Where should I add my "`mask`" class in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention if it's a particular node TYPE that you're after.  If it is, then please clarify that.  You also don't say what the `.mask` div actually contains, so I'm going to assume it contains nothing and the content is the background image.  If this is the case then you can just put `<div class="mask"></div>` anywhere.  The `position: absolute` should mean that it won't dislodge any other content anyway.

I'm also not sure why you need `!important` after `width`.  If this class is something you're declaring then it shouldn't get overriden unless YOU want it to.  If you're worried about it then I'd namespace the class instead (ie `.mytheme-mask`).

**EDIT**

Put it anywhere, but write it like this:

```
<?php if (!drupal_is_front_page() && !$teaser) { ?>
  <div class="mask"></div>
<?php };?>
```

This means that if the page is a content page (not the front page) and not a teaser then place your div in the node.

Comment: Chapabu, i don't have template tpl files. So, i want make this by node.tpl

Comment: Wait...what?  You don't have the template files, so you want to do it with template files?  I don't follow.

Comment: Sorry, i don't have page--front.tpl etc files. But have got node.tpl and want embed this class in this file.

Comment: So you only want it on the home page, but you haven't got access to the home page template?  Correct?

Comment: No, only content.

Comment: Any particular content type?  Or just everything EXCEPT the front page?  You're going to have to help me before I can help you.

Comment: I want it all full content but not show teaser.

Comment: I've edited my answer.  If this isn't what you need then you need to revisit your question and be more specific.